# VBScript cannot create folder

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, uft14

I have a simple script that perfectly works on a computer. The script is written in VBScript and ran using UFT (Unified Functional Testing).

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objFolder, strDirectory

strDirectory = "Path" 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
```

However, when I try to run this code on another computer it didn't work. I changed the path to another path which corresponds to the new computer. The surprise comes when I try to run the code without using the variable `strDirectory`:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objFolder, strDirectory

strDirectory = "Path" 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("path")
```

which works fine in the new computer.

Does anyone know why is this happening? How can a script work in a computer but not in another computer? And moreover, how can the script work in this new computer when not using the `strDirectory` variable to store the path?

Comment: What error do you get when you don't hardcode the path?

Comment: You may not have permission to create a folder of the given location. Try to create manually and check.

Comment: Panka, I got the error "Cannot create Folder. The path is incorrect" It was something like this. I cannot acces the computer since friday, but I remember that the error was something like this. My feeling was that the script couldn't create the folder  cause it was a wrong path, but as I mentioned in the question, writting the same path explicitly in the function worked fine.

Comment: So, are you trying to say that the only difference between the code that worked and the code that didn't work is where you moved the literal path string from a variable to just putting it directly into the function call? Is your code example simplified from your actual working code, and if so, perhaps your variable is getting changed somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

Try running using the entire path:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objFolder, strDirectory

strDirectory = "Path" 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\\path")
```